# Is it possible to add consecutive columns in AWK

Tags: awk

So I have a large file that contains count values in columns. A shorter version of the file is as follows:

```
Id,Sample1,Sample2,Sample3,Sample4,Sample5,Sample6,Sample7,Sample8,Sample9,Sample10,Sample11,Sample12,Sample13,Sample14,Sample15,Sample16,Sample17,Sample18,Sample19,Sample20,Sample21,Sample22,Sample23,Sample24
bar,80,167,1419,2973,16846,31523,257,466,4004,6662,13862,22205,116,284,786,1198,467,853,3333,6054,18122,34030,22,41
foo,29,71,582,1143,6382,11466,99,138,1388,2176,4337,7043,55,106,349,600,211,319,1468,2418,8661,15285,12,12
qaz,23,59,478,904,4919,8538,85,147,1553,2463,5061,8094,56,84,271,411,176,291,1268,2132,7219,12436,6,13
etc,27,43,464,970,4101,8092,90,111,1441,2174,4954,7940,41,85,249,378,130,234,1075,1856,5920,10854,9,18
zxc,15,34,332,609,2568,4652,53,82,989,1592,3219,5034,46,87,315,479,104,170,759,1297,4926,8171,2,9
qwe,9,20,146,310,2932,5391,48,94,842,1349,2823,4430,23,34,115,235,113,172,811,1362,4178,7576,8,10
asd,16,39,388,687,2796,5303,51,110,763,1216,2610,4165,50,79,351,603,113,156,824,1345,3337,6168,4,9
abc,6,16,91,192,385,654,21,32,326,496,7884,12266,10,19,56,89,41,62,251,367,1545,2657,,4
xyz,14,33,249,538,1634,2983,28,71,555,952,1697,2712,23,34,111,167,95,148,650,1131,3204,5814,4,12
```

What I would like to do is to sum consecutive columns (sample1 + sample2, sample3 + sample4, ...) such that:

```
bar,247,4392,...
foo,100,1725,...
qaz,82,1382,...
...
```

I've tried for loops over NF but it seems to print everything on separate lines, also the numbers aren't really accurate either...

```
> awk -F, 'NR > 1 {for(i=2; i<=NF; i=i+2){print ($i + $i+1)}}' short.csv 
161
2839
33693
515
8009
27725
233
1573
935
6667
36245
45
59
1165
...
```

Is it possible to do this in awk or similar light-weight, command line script-fu?

Comment: @Rahul The values under columns SampleN, tried to clarify it in the question body.

Comment: replace `$i+1` by `$(i+1)`.

Comment: @meuh That solves the addition problem, the values are still on separate rows however. I am also not sure how to get the first column in on the same line

Comment: use `printf "%d,",...`  for `print`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem you had with `$i + $i+1` was effectively it was doing `$i + $i + 1` which isn't what you wanted.

Instead something like

```
awk -F, 'NR > 1 { printf("%s",$1)
                  for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) { printf(",%d",$i+$(i+1)) }
                  print ""
                }
'
```

Results:

```
bar,247,4392,48369,723,10666,36067,400,1984,1320,9387,52152,63
foo,100,1725,17848,237,3564,11380,161,949,530,3886,23946,24
qaz,82,1382,13457,232,4016,13155,140,682,467,3400,19655,19
etc,70,1434,12193,201,3615,12894,126,627,364,2931,16774,27
zxc,49,941,7220,135,2581,8253,133,794,274,2056,13097,11
qwe,29,456,8323,142,2191,7253,57,350,285,2173,11754,18
asd,55,1075,8099,161,1979,6775,129,954,269,2169,9505,13
abc,22,283,1039,53,822,20150,29,145,103,618,4202,4
xyz,47,787,4617,99,1507,4409,57,278,243,1781,9018,16
```

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you.. I suppose it's in general nicer to put that script inside a separate file? I say that mostly since it's easier to manage the parentheses over multiple lines..

Comment: That's a matter of taste.  I tend to inline short awk scripts like this so there's less external file dependencies.  `awk` doesn't care too much about newlines in this scenario so you could even put it all on one line with `;` separators; `awk -F, 'NR > 1 { printf("%s",$1) ; for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=2) { printf(",%d",$i+$(i+1)) } ; print "" }'`